# Spring mock MVC unit test with controller advice

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-test

I am trying to test my controller advice exception handling. I have registered my controller advice to my mockmvc:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice())
            .build();
```

I can see in the console the test is picking up the exception handling methods:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in com.myapp...ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice
```

The ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice class has a handler method for a security exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler(SecurityException.class)
```

When my unit test throws a SecurityException, the test fails with a stacktrace instead of invoking the handler method in the controller advice.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Normally, Security Exeption happen very soon, before Spring dispatcherservlet. So it throws exception before reach ControllerAdvice. For Security Exception, base on some specific case, you have to correctly setup.

Answer (score 7):

Annotate your Spring mock mvc test with

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(YourControllerAdvice.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing `@ControllerAdvice`, I would suggest not to use standalone setup, but rather load full Spring Context duting test:

Something like:

```
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(context)
        .addFilters(springSecurityFilter)
        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
        .build();
```

Comment: When I use the webAppContextSetup Spring doesn't find the controller advice... it does find it when running the app normally.

Comment: Oh you probably need to inject also Spring Security into your test mockMvc configuration to make it working. I  updated my answer.

Comment: It's still not finding it with spring security. I added a println to the post construct of the controller advice to ensure it's being loaded by Spring and it is... the test just isn't using it for some reason